# Notice the map and chat

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there any way I can not forget seeing the chat and the minimap while I play? I mean, I look at them but when I focus on farming or when I try to kill an enemy under turret I completely forget about the map and the chat and I'm very vulnerable for that time to gangs and everything. Is there anything I can do to remember to look at those two often while I play?

Comment: Ask a friend of you to stand behind you. Everytime you die because you dont look on map he gives you a neck bludger. This bases on conditioning, Learning from mistakes and Learning through punishment. I think you nerver will not look on the map after 2 hours :D

Comment: I noticed that my map awareness was a lot better after playing Jungle for a few days.  Maybe you could give that a try.  Play a few rounds as jungler, and make sure to check *all* the lanes after/during each individual camp.

Answer (score 6):

A pretty cool thing I heard, that there is a eye dominance (ocular dominance). If you are for example right dominant, then your minimap belongs on the right side. And if your left eye is dominant then the minimap belongs on the left side. You can change these settings ingame :) How to find out which eye is dominant: Point to an object in the distance with a finger. Then close one eye. If the finger is still 'correctly pointing to the object' (rather than a little bit to the left or right), the currently open eye is your dominant eye. That helped me as well ;) I wish you good luck with it

And another good tip is to give yourself that task to have a look at the minimap after you last hitted 1 minion :) that will give you some regularity on looking at the minimap

Comment: It doesn't work to test out which one is my dominant one, if I try it my focus always changes which means that either I see the thing pointed at double or I see my finger double :p

Comment: yeh of course it changes... xD you have to open BOTH eyes at first. Then you take your finger as target. You have to remember the position where the finger was when you had both eyes open. Now when you close one eye, and the finger doesn't move it's position then this eye is the dominant one. If you close your eye and it changes the position then this eye is your "not dominant" eye. It's that easy :P I heard as well that some people don't even have a dominant eye. That could be your case as well

Comment: I found out that my left eye is my dominant one. Even though I've never heard about this theory before I find it kinda interesting. I'm gonna put my map from the left side and tell you if it works. Thanks a lot for all the help, I greatly appreciate it! ^^

Comment: No Problem, I tried it as well but damn ! every time you want to watch your items and gold; you see the minimap and when you want to have a look at the map, you see your items and gold xD It takes it's time but it pays off ;)

Comment: I tried it once on normal.. Man, I felt like the whole screen was upside down at some points xD I'll get used to it soon enough I guess and I hope xD

Answer (score 2):

Map awareness only comes with practice. By "practicing" looking at the map, you will learn this skill so that it becomes automatic.

Before we look at what you can do to improve your awareness, let's look at what stops you from looking at the map in the first place. The two most common factors are:

- Trading/fighting with enemy laners -- just before ganks, many people will initiate trades to divert focus from the map. Even high ranked players fall bait to this!
- Farming -- just make sure to be doing other things when you are NOT farming: harassing, looking at the map, thinking about the situation, etc.

So the best times to look at the map are when you are not doing either of these. A quick glance can help not only you, but your allies as well!

Prompts can be useful when getting into the habit of looking at the map:

- Every two minions, glance at the map.
- When the enemy laners suddenly adopt aggressive positions, take a quick glance at the map. (But don't get hit by the thresh hook while you do this!)
- MIA pings!!
- Ally/enemy deaths.

Comment: I will definitely try the methods you told me. I was thinking of doing something like that but I didn't really knew when should I do it. Thanks for the suggestions and help!!

Answer (score 0):

New chat messages will make your chat log appear automatically. If you still can't notice it, you can actually make it bigger (drag the corner of the log).

As for the minimap, anything *important* should be expressed as pings by your teammates, so you will hear and notice it. You can also increase the UI scale in the settings menu.

I don't think there is much to remind you to see the minimap. It's already huge. It has annoying pings too.

Comment: That doesn't help at all when the jungler comes to gank you and your team isn't watching the map for you.

Comment: @dphil: Isn't that what wards are for? Any sensible team will notice.

Comment: Has nothing to do with being sensible.  He's have a hard time noticing the map, why would his team easily notice the map?  Wards won't do anything if you don't watch the map.  I'm assuming it's a bronze/silver/gold player where they won't have their team helping to watch the map too.  (Even higher elos sometime's won't ping people back when the enemy is in clear vision of the map.)

Comment: @dphil: If he has problems watching the map, increasing the minimap HUD scale sounds like a perfectly acceptable idea to me. Hard to see? Make it bigger. What's wrong with that?

Comment: I was responding to you.  If he is having a hard time watching the map, making it bigger won't be much help.  He's still zoning in on what is going on with his character that he forgets about the map.  Larger map doesn't solve tunnel visioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can try playing champion like twisted fate that rely manly on the minimap to be effective.